# Color mixing and White light

Tags: visible-light

White light can be produced by the mixing of red, green and blue light.
If one mixes red and green light, one gets yellow.
Why, then, does the mixing of yellow and blue light produce green, rather than white?

Comment: my answer here is appropriate https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/605951/what-actually-is-white-light/605969#605969

Comment: Welcome E, Stander to Physics SE. It is not true that mixing yellow and blue light produces green light; ideally it will produce white light. Mixing yellow and blue pigments, however, produces green pigment. Check out [additive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_color) and [subtractive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractive_color) colours, and [colour mixing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_mixing).